# How can I scroll to the object where I’m unable to get the scrolling text?

Tags: android, flutter, testing, mobile, katalon-studio

I’m doing the Android mobile testing and I’m stuck in a situation where I have to scroll in the application to click on the desired object item.

As Katalon provides the **scrollToText()** function and here we need to pass the **text** then it will scroll down to that **text**.

But, In my case, the object hierarchy is like below:

[image]

In the above Image, You can see I’m unable to get the text of the scrolling object.

Now, Can anyone please help me with how can I scroll down to the intended scrolling object?

**PS: I have tried with the help of content-desc but it didn’t work.**